# OpenGL performs very bad on laptop

Tags: opengl, performance, windows, nvidia

I'm trying to write a game using C and OpenGL, I wrote some rendering code and camera, but the game is very laggy, framerate is so low (probably around 10-15fps), however, if I launch the game through Steam as a non Steam game my framerate jumps up to 800 immediately after Steam Overlay loads. The game works fine on my computer and my friend's laptop even without launching with Steam.

And I'm running Windows 10 Pro, 8GB ram, Nvidia GTX 1050 4GB, Intel Core i5-7300HQ

Comment: Make sure you tell your nvidia driver to run the game with your GPU and not with your on-board chip.

Comment: I did! But even on Intel GPU the performance is 300+ FPS when I run it with Steam.

Comment: Are you maybe running it through a debugger?

Comment: No, I compile with clang and make, so I would have to run lldb manually which I don't

Comment: Are you running exactly the same executable with steam? If not, maybe the compiler optimization flags are different.

Comment: Yes, I only have 1 executable, I compile with O3, but I have tried different optimization levels, didn't do anything to the performance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced. This one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Reinstalling Windows fixed my problem.

Comment: So it was a driver problem.